# MVCSiteMapProvider : Different Output depending on Environment

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am maintaining a huge web app, and there's one issue I am having and I don't know where to look.

The Web app is using MVCSiteMapProvider 3.6 to provide the breadcrumb. In this release, I had to take the output of Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath().ToString which usually looks like this :

```
<a href="/">Home</a> &gt; <a href="/Account">Account</a> &gt; Log On
```

and feed everything to a function so it outputs this :

> {title: "Home", href: "/"}, {title: "Account", href: "/Account"}, {title:"Log On"}

so in turn it can be used by a Content Delivery Network (which I have absolutely no control on) that builds the breadcrumb with it.

But for some reason I don't really understand, the output of the Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath().ToString method is completely different in the QA environment. In Development and Testing, that worked completely fine.
In QA, the output looks more like a list, with the "ol" and "li" tags.

I am still a rookie, and I can't think of anything to would make that output change in that specific environment. My time is running out and I really have to narrow down my search.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the QA people didn't follow the install guide and overwrote with the new build instead of copying from scratch. The DisplayTemplates folder in Views/Shared was still there from a previous version and made the output change.